# Batch rename w/ Powershell - needs to look up and match file_id with title in csv

Tags: windows, excel, powershell, batch-file

I already know batch renaming is possible via Powershell, but so far I didn't find an answer that solves my problem:

I have a staple of pdfs named with an ID:

```
Eg. 
332906.pdf
331339.pdf
343807.pdf
...
```

I produced a simple CSV out of my spreadsheet which contains the id in the first column and the corresponding filename i want in the second one:

```
appid;Fullname with I.D.
332906;Mike Miller_332906;
331339;Tom Hanks_331339;
343807;Scarlett Jo_343807;
```

....
....

I have to do that on my office computer so I can't download additional programms or use programming lanugages, all I have is the cmd box and Powershell.

Can I do that?

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Spreadsheet changed to CSV; CSV Example added

Comment: Save the spreadsheet as a `csv` file and then add to your question a line from that file. A sample of the data will be necessary to answer this.

Comment: Can you use php, Python etc

Comment: @TobyAllen From OP: **I have to do that on my office computer so I can't download additional programms or use programming lanugages, all I have is the cmd box and Powershell**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a problem with the column heading as-is, but if you change it to below:

```
appid,Fullname_ID
332906,Mike Miller_332906,
331339,Tom Hanks_331339,
343807,Scarlett Jo_343807,
```

You can run this simple script to do the file rename:

```
$c = import-csv .\path\to.csv
$c | % { mv "$($_.appid).pdf" "$($_.Fullname_ID).pdf" }
```

What this does is create a PowerShell object containing the data from the csv file.

`$c | % { .. }` means iterate over all the rows in the csv and run the code in the blocks `{...}`

`$_` represents each row, and from that you can access the columns using `.appid` and `.Fullname_ID`. The move (`mv`) command is what you will use to do the rename.

Comment: Did the job perfectly fine. So many thanks! :-)
Also for the detailed explanations - I like to understand what I'm doing. 
My colleagues are renaming everyone manually ^^

Comment: Perfect, don't tell them you're using a script and it'll look like you're just super fast ;-)